# Spotify Application: Failing to load

Tags: spotify

I've hunted the many topics about this, but can't figure it out.
I downloaded the test application provided by spotify, located at: https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial to create my first Spotify App.

I have created my folder /[home_directory]/Spotify/app/api-tutorial

The files within are: [image]

The contents of the manifest are:

```
{
    "AppDescription": {
        "en": "A tutorial app for Spotify Apps API"
    },
    "AppIcon": {
        "36x18": "tutorial.png"
    },
    "AppName": {
        "en": "Spotify Apps API Tutorial"
    },
    "BundleIdentifier": "api-tutorial",
    "BundleType": "Application",
    "BundleVersion": "0.1",
    "DefaultTabs": [
        {
            "arguments": "index",
            "title": {
                "en": "Home"
            }
        },
        {
            "arguments": "tabs",
            "title": {
                "en": "How to use tabs"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Dependencies": {
      "api": "0.2.3",
      "util": "0.1.0",
      "resources": "0.2.2"
  },
    "RequiredInterface": 1,
    "RequiredPermissions": [
        "http://api.twitter.com",
        "http://o.scdn.co",
        "https://*.googleapis.com",
        "https://*.gstatic.com",
        "https://*.gmaptiles.co.kr",
        "https://earthbuilder.google.com",
        "https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com",
        "https://raw.github.com",
        "http://tile.cloudmade.com",
        "http://*.tile.cloudmade.com",
        "https://graph.facebook.com",
        "https://gist.github.com/",
        "http://search.twitter.com/",
        "http://amsterdam.last.fm",
        "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/",
        "http://developer.echonest.com"
    ],
    "SupportedLanguages": [
        "en"
    ],
    "VendorIdentifier": "co.mager"
}
```

My account is activated as a developer.. but I can't get it to load:
[image]

Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the application a folder level too deep — it should go `~/Spotify/api-tutorial`.